# How can I connect my flask app to my SQLite3 database?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite

Hi I am trying to create a customer feedback form; I have managed to create the pages I need, but I am having difficulty connecting my app to my SQLite3 database.

So in my code python code I am trying to collect the data from the customer feedback form and hold it in a database.

In the feedback form they will be prompted to input their name, choose some answers from a drop-box selection, and to write a comment at the end.

The answers will be housed in the database (for future reference - like reports etc) and the user will be redirected back to the home page where they will be able to see their name & comment (taken from the feedback form).

I have watched tutorials on sqlite3 which was kind of easy to understand & execute (a lot easier for me than MySQL) but I'm missing something because it won't connect to my database.

my python flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, g
from functools import wraps
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "random_character_generator" # this would be random or anything the developer wants
app.database = "gymdatabase.db"

conn = sqlite3.connect(app.database)
c = conn.cursor()

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.database)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('select * from posts')
    posts = [dict(name=row[0], welcome=row[1], equipment=row[2], cleanliness=row[3], interaction=row[4], comments=row[5], contact=row[6]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('gym_index.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/feedback', methods=['POST'])
def feedback():
    return render_template('gym_feedback.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    g.db = connect_db()
    name = request.form['name']
    welcome = request.form['welcome']
    equipment = request.form['equipment']
    cleanliness = request.form['cleanliness']
    interaction = request.form['interaction']
    comment = request.form['comment']
    contact = request.form['yes_no']
    conn.commit()
    cur = g.db.execute(select * from posts)
    posts = [dict(name=row[0], welcome=row[1], equipment=row[2], cleanliness=row[3], interaction=row[4], comments=row[5], contact=row[6]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return redirect(url_for('home', posts=posts))
```

When I try to submit a feedback form I get:
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.

I can upload the html file on request; I'm not too sure if I have space to do so along with my python file.

Comment: What do you mean, "it won't connect"? What happens? What error do you get? (Note, nowhere in this code do you ever actually insert anything into the db.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is due to your line `conn.commit()` in your `process()` function. You declare `conn = sqlite3.connect(app.database)` when Flask first starts, but each function defined with the `@app.route(...)` function decorator gets called in a different thread in response to HTTP requests (as defined in the aforementioned function decorator). You probably want to do something like this:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    ...
    db = connect_db()
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from posts")
    results = cur.fetchall()
    ...
```

You can see this link for further documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

I can edit my answer if you provide more context regarding where your code is failing.

Comment: Thanks I tried out your suggestion it still doesn’t connect to my database (the information passed is not sent to my database). When I press the submit button it redirects to the home page but nothing is posted or stored into database.

Comment: If you're doing some sort of update on your database, you need to put a `cur.commit()` call after your `cur.execute(...)` call. In my example, all you're doing is retrieving every row from your database and storing it in the results variable.

Comment: thanks Pablo; ive managed to create an empty table called posts and once the user has filled in their feedback form the data is supposed to be sent to the database.  the just the name of the user and their comments should be taken from the database and redirected to the home page at the beginning.

Comment: if possible would I be able to send/email you what I have maybe you could see where I a potentially going wrong..